# Using polymorphic JAX-WS webservice parameters

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I have this simple JAX-WS WebService:

```
@WebService
public class AnimalFeedingService {
    @WebMethod
    public void feed(@WebParam(name = "animal") Animal animal) {
        // Whatever
    }
}

@XmlSeeAlso({ Dog.class, Cat.class })
public abstract class Animal {
    private double weight;
    private String name;
    // Also getters and setters
}

public class Dog extends Animal {}

public class Cat extends Animal {}
```

I create a client and call `feed` with an instance of `Dog`.

```
Animal myDog = new Dog();
myDog .setName("Rambo");
myDog .setWeight(15);
feedingServicePort.feed(myDog);
```

The animal in the body of the SOAP call looks like this:

```
<animal>
    <name>Rambo</name>
    <weight>15</weight>
</animal>
```

and I get an `UnmarshallException` because `Animal` is abstract.

Is there a way to have Rambo unmarshalled as an instance of class `Dog`? What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you might have guessed, XML parser is not able to determine the exact subtype of animal you used when requesting because anything it sees is generic `<animal>` and a set of tags that are common to all types, hence the error. What JAX-WS implementation do you use? It is the responsibility of the client to properly wrap polymorphic types when sending request. In [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org) (I checked your code against newest 2.3.2 version) the SOAP request body looks like this:

```
<animal xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:dog">
    <name>Rambo</name>
    <weight>15.0</weight>
</animal>
```

The `xsi:type="ns2:dog"` is crucial here. It seems like your JAX-WS client is sending incorrect request that confuses the server. Try sending this request with some other client, like SoapUI, to see whether your server reacts properly.

As I said, it works just fine with Spring/Apache CXF and exactly the same code you've provided, I only extracted Java interface to make CXF happy:

```
public interface AnimalFeedingService {

    @WebMethod
    void feed(@WebParam(name = "animal") Animal animal);

}

@WebService
@Service
public class AnimalFeedingServiceImpl implements AnimalFeedingService {
    @Override
    @WebMethod
    public void feed(@WebParam(name = "animal") Animal animal) {
        // Whatever
    }
}
```

...and the server/client glue code:

```
<jaxws:endpoint implementor="#animalFeedingService" address="/animal"/>

<jaxws:client id="animalFeedingServiceClient"
              serviceClass="com.blogspot.nurkiewicz.test.jaxws.AnimalFeedingService"
              address="http://localhost:8080/test/animal">
</jaxws:client>
```

Comment: Using xsi:type from SoapUI worked, the problem must be in my client. Thanks.